# Finding the peak on a density plot

Tags: r

I've created a series of numbers using the `rbeta` function.

```
set.seed(123)
n = 100000
p1.12.2 = rbeta(n, 0.3225928, 1.2903712)
p4.7.2 = (rbeta(n, 0.3488823,  3.1399407)^2)
E2 = p4.7.2*p1.12.2
```

This runs fine but I would like to find the mode of E2, so I've done this by getting the peak of the density plot.

```
d = density(E2)
i = which.max(d$y)
M2 = d$x[i]
M2
```

I keep getting a negative value for the mode. But the beta distribution is confined to 0-1. Any ideas where the negative values are coming from or is there another way to get the mode of a bin?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode) maybe

Comment: Thanks, that did work. But is there anyway of not having to manually retype the value.

Comment: I don't understand the question. All you need to do is `Mode(E2)`

Comment: `Mode(E2)` produces the output that says the value is numeric. `mlv(E2)` produces the mode, but in the format as follows:
`Mode (most likely value): 5.080008e-06 
Bickel's modal skewness: 0.256018 
Call: mlv.default(x = E2) `
So its a non-numeric output. Is there a way of pulling out the 5.08e-06 without having to retype each time.

Comment: I have no idea what you talking about. You asked for the mode it gives you the mode (which is `6.091736e-08`). I don't understand what other difficulties you have.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think we should check what this function does step by step. I have a feeling that the fact that each E2 value is unique breaks the function. If I do E2 = sort(E2), then the mode value it returns changes. It seems that in this case it will return the first E2 value as the mode. Have a look please...

Comment: It maybe a package issue on my part, but `Mode(E2)` does not work for me. The moodest package works where I get the mode using the function `mlv(E2)`. My issue was that this package doesn't produce a numeric value. I should be able to use `capture.output(mlv)` to capture the part I'm looking for though. Thanks.

Comment: Did you define `Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x);
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}`?

Comment: That worked. Apologies for the confusion, I'm a relatively novice user. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, concerning what I mentioned before about the Mode function try this `Mode(E2)` and `Mode(sort(E2, decreasing = T))` which give different results.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a "problem" due to how kernel density estimates work. 
What about approximating your peak value using a histogram and specifying a large number of breaks?

```
h = hist(E2, breaks=500)
i = which.max(h$counts)
M2 = h$mids[i]
M2
```

Try different values of `breaks`.

Comment: It is an approximation though. Check carefully if that will cause any problems before you proceed. Glad I helped.

Comment: The traditional way of getting the mode is to count how many times each element appears in your vector. But in your case E2 has many decimal points and the way it was created makes each value unique. The kernel estimates try to "count" appearances in very small areas around each value. So if a value is so close to zero it might create small negative values to cover a small area around your minimum value which is close to zero. With histogram you won't go below your minimum value. I'm not sure if there's a way to do that using the density function.